# .bashrc file not being processed/loaded

Tags: boot, ssh, bash

Some time last week (week-ending April 16th), my raspberry pi stopped loading the .bashrc file whenever I connect to the unit. I have to manually run the .bashrc file using source for it to work. What gives?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'd like to point out that your hostname (badassmachinev2) might not be appropriate under SE's rules.

Comment: I assume you're connecting over SSH, right?  (Not locally or via serial or rsh or anything weird like that.)

Comment: @Hydraxan14 yes, I connect through SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash can be started in three ways: as a *login* shell (interactive or not), as an *interactive* shell (but not a login shell), and as neither. (All following quotations are from the "Invocation" section of the [bash manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).)

Bash is started as a login shell when you log in at the text VGA console, serial console or via ssh:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

Note that `.bashrc` is not executed in this case. Most Linux distributions, including Raspbian, supply the user with a default `~/.profile` that includes the following lines:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

If you've added a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` file, your `~/.profile` file will no longer be executed, and that might be why your `~/.bashrc` is no longer being sourced on login. If not, check the contents of your `~/.profile` to see if these lines have been changed or removed.

#### Additional Information

`~/.bashrc` is sourced automatically if you start an interactive (but non-login) shell, such as by typing `bash` at the command prompt:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

Whether `~/.bashrc`, some other file, or no file at all is sourced when a non-interactive shell is started, such as with `bash -c "somecommand"` depends on the setting of the `$BASH_ENV` variable:

> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.

Comment: Thank you. I'm AFK now, but will look into ~/.profile when I get home.

Comment: Thank you very much. Removing the `~/.bash_profile` file fixed the problem :)